# Tool for managing and refactoring java .properties files

Tags: java, properties, refactoring

Is there any tool for managing java .properties files that is able to:

- rename keys in .properties files along with their usage in .java and .jspx files (something like Eclipse's refactoring)
- find keys that are used in .java and .jspx files but not present in a .propertis file
- find keys from .properties files that are not used in .java and .jspx files
- find duplicit key values?

I have found the [bundlizer tool](http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/useful_tools_bundlizer_removes_duplicate), but were not able to obtain it.

Answer (score 2):

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) has a lot of advanced features supporting development with [properties files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/properties-files.html). There's a support for [i18n with properties files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-bundle.html#editing) as well.

Comment: +1 It is really comfortably to refactoring properties string with IDEA

Comment: I was hoping for some small standalone tool, because I have to use JDeveloper :( But thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: The second and third link are dead now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standalone tool called [i18nBinder](http://code.google.com/p/i18n-binder/) which is based on an Apache Ant task. It can generate a Excel (xls) file for your property file folders and write changes within the xls file back to the property files.

It has also the capability to generate a Java source code facade for your property files. If you use such a facade the Java compiler will take care of missing properties.

Unfortunately it will have little use for your legacy code, like hard coded properties within your jsp files :-/